# Редактирование тега title

Tags: css3, html

Возможно ли редактирование тега title, если да то как? Я имею ввиду изменить цвет текста, шрифт, размер и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, у данного тега нет ни атрибутов, ни css-свойств, которые он бы мог принять. Это все равно, что в мета-тегах keywords или description пытаться изменить шрифт или его цвет и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Создать tooltip на ховер

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: @markuper, человек спрашивал о **теге** title, а не об атрибуте title. Не вводите в заблуждение.

Comment: понятно, тоесть не как, ну ладно, спасибо и на этом всем, так хотя бы про tooltip узнал